# My.Settings Serialization, custom object?

Tags: vb.net, serialization, my.settings

I am having a problem saving an arraylist of a object I created.  I implemented ISerializable and I can manually use Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer to serialize and deserialize it.

When I add it to my arraylist and use the save method it doesn't save.  When I reopen my project my arraylist is null.  Even if it had other information that wasn't my object, it will toss all of it out.

To test if it was my object,  I threw some strings in the array saves and restarted my program and they were still there.  Add my object and save / restart and Null.

Comment: objects cant be serialized directly, they have to be a 'concrete' type like string, integer etc.  if it is truly a custom object (like a class you wrote), you may be able to serialize the essential properties which it is made up of.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but a little more involved.

[Part 1](http://cushen.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/vb-net%E2%80%99s-my-settings-and-custom-objectsclasses-part-one-requirements-for-your-class/)